# Free falling bodies: why air resistance is not considered?

Tags: classical-mechanics

We affirm that free falling bodies are by definition bodies that are subject to the sole force of gravity. We state that free falling bodies fall through equal distances in equal times regardless their different weight. Most of the experiments that show this evidence are executed in normal conditions here on earth; for example, we see that dropping a bowling ball and a ping-pong ball, the two objects touch the ground at the same moment despite their different weight. 
What I don’t understand is how we can state something about free falling objects from experiments that are not about free falling objects, because the ping-pong ball and the bowling ball, for example, are also under the influence of air inertia.

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about. The ping pong ball and bowling ball will not hit the ground at the same time in air

Comment: As far as I know no physicist says a bowling ball and a ping pong ball fall at the same rate in air. However the experiment has been done in a vacuum and there they do fall at the same rate.

Comment: i see many experiments on YouTube that describe this behavior https://youtu.be/_mCC-68LyZM

Comment: The two balls in the video have the same shape and cross sectional area, so drag is going to be nearly the same for both balls. The example of a bowling ball with a pingpong ball doesn't hold since, although they are the same shape, they don't have the same cross sectional area. In fact, the drag equation tells us $$F_D = \frac{1}{2}\rho v^2 C_D A $$ In a vacuum what you say it's true since there's no drag

Comment: @DavideMorgante thank you for your explanation

Comment: The effect of air resistance is generally negligible for the short duration of their fall, it doesn't make much of a difference, in fact most qns regarding free fall specifically ask us to ignore air resistance

Answer (score 1):

> we see that dropping a bowling ball and a ping-pong ball, the two objects touch the ground at the same moment despite their different weight.

Not when I do the experiment. In fact Galileo had a hard time convincing his colleagues that, without air resistance, they would fall at the same rate. His genius was to design experiments which  reduced the effect of air resistance to a negligible amount.

Answer (score 1):

This is how things are presented in the introductory physics. The experiments are deliberately chosen in such a way that the presence of the air friction can be neglected: e.g., one chooses a bowling ball and a ping pong ball. If one chose a sheet of paper and a sheet of metal, they clearly would fall with different speeds.

For a ball to experience significant adjustment of its velocity due to the air resistance, it has to fall a much bigger distance OR it has to move in something more viscous than air. In fact, a friction force on a ball falling in viscous liquid was an experiment done in my freshman year at the university.

Comment: This! In physics it is really easy to encounter systems that are either very hard or impossible to solve. Often one has to resort to the simplest of cases. By extensively styding these simple systems you might learn something that helps you solve (slightly) more complicated systems. The act of adding air friction makes the problem a lot more difficult.